# import data from into elasticsearch index using json file and curl command

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to import data located in a json file into an elasticsearch index using the curl command.

The index is being created using `kibana` as follow

```
  PUT employees
  {
    "mappings" : {
        "properties":{
            "fields": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {"type": "text"},
                    "nom": {"type": "text"},
                    "prenom": {"type": "text"},
                    "sexe": {"type": "text"},
                    "socials": {
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {"type": "text"},
                            "url": {"type": "text"} 
                        }
                    },
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running the follwing command to import the data

```
 curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @users.json
```

the `users.json` file contains the data represented as follow

```
 {"index": {"_index": "users", "_type": "user", "_id": 1}}
 {"fields": {"id": "5fe60ae52b40e53609c803ec","nom": "Jessica","prenom": "Herrera","aboutMe": "anim","socials": [{"name": "faacebook","url": "https://www.facebook.com/profile?id=5445546"},{"name": "linkedin","url": "https://www.linkedin.com/profile?id=5445546"}],"affiliations": [{"organisation": "ANARCO","equipe": "developpement","pays": "Russian Federation","dateD": "2013-06-03T00:00:00Z" ,"dateF": "2013-06-03T00:00:00Z" }]}}
```

Here is the error I get

```
 "type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [users] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type
```

I've read many resources but still not able to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping
> update to [users] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type

You are getting the above error because of the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/removal-of-types.html) in Elasticsearch 6.x, in which the mapping types were deprecated.

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 7.0.0 or later no longer accept a
> *default* mapping. Indices created in 6.x will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types are deprecated in APIs in 7.0, with
> breaking changes to the index creation, put mapping, get mapping, put
> template, get template and get field mappings APIs.

You need to modify your JSON as -

```
{"index": {"_index": "users", "_id": 1}}
{"fields": {"id": "5fe60ae52b40e53609c803ec","nom": "Jessica","prenom": "Herrera","aboutMe": "anim","socials": [{"name": "faacebook","url": "https://www.facebook.com/profile?id=5445546"},{"name": "linkedin","url": "https://www.linkedin.com/profile?id=5445546"}],"affiliations": [{"organisation": "ANARCO","equipe": "developpement","pays": "Russian Federation","dateD": "2013-06-03T00:00:00Z" ,"dateF": "2013-06-03T00:00:00Z" }]}}
```

Comment: But doing this way, I cannot get a document by id, this `http://localhost:9200/users/2` get request doesn't work, it gives me an `incorrect http method for the uri users/2` error. Even if I give a default type like `users/default/2` it doesn't return anything.